# I can copy El Capitan installation on thumb drive but it is not visible when I hold option key on restart

Tags: macos, ssd

I am using OS X El Capitan on Macbook 7.1 (Mid-2010). My thumbdrive is detected inside El Capitan and I can make it bootable and put El Capitan installation on it by using terminal command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
```

but thumb drive is not visible when I hold option on restart. Therefore I can't install El Capitan on my new SSD that I have. When I install using terminal, I get this message at the end of the process, in terminal:

> Couldn't mount dmg /Volumes/Install OS X El Capitan/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg (error code 112)Mount of outer dmg failed.

After this, when I ran the hdiutil:

```
hdiutil verify Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

on the thumb drive, I got:

> Checksumming Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)… Protective Master Boot Record (MBR :: checksum failed with error 1000.  ............................................................................................................................................................... calculated CRC32 $00000000, expected CRC32 $BE5D6293 hdiutil: verify: checksum of "Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" is INVALID hdiutil: verify failed - image data corrupted

So the error can be either on the installation or the thumb drive itself (bad drive).

Sometimes I get this message at the end of the installation thumbdrive making process:

> Failed to copy kernelcache, The file “kernelcache” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

I want to install fresh clean install of El Capitan on my brand new SSD that I bought, and somehow Apple is preventing me from using it. Any help anyone?

Answer (score 4):

- (Download the latest El Capitan Installer (10.11.3))
- Open Terminal and check the hash of InstallESD.dmg:

  ```
  shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
  ```

  The result (as of March, 5th 2016) should be: 526a6f7a619ef86f42acc026276aab351ea27614
- Insert your thumb drive
- Get the disk identifier of the thumb drive with

  ```
  diskutil list
  ```

  Below I assume the disk identifier of the thumb drive is disk1
- Delete any MBR on the thumb drive:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk1
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=512 count=1
  diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk1
  ```
- Open Disk Utility and partition the thumb drive:

  Options...: GUID partition table
  Name: Untitled
  Format: Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)
- Create the El Capitan Installer thumb drive:

  ```
  sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app --nointeraction
  ```

  The output looks like this:

  ```
  Erasing Disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%...100%...
  Copying installer files to disk...
  Copy complete.
  Making disk bootable...
  Copying boot files...
  Copy complete.
  Done.
  ```
- Check the InstallESD.dmg on the thumb drive:

  ```
  hdiutil verify /Volumes/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
  ```

  The output should look like this:

  ```
  Checksumming Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)…
  Protective Master Boot Record (MBR :: verified   CRC32 $8A0AD7CD
  Checksumming GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1)…
   GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1): verified   CRC32 $E61CC7FE
  Checksumming GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2)…
  GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Tabl: verified   CRC32 $8F9F9AF5
  Checksumming  (Apple_Free : 3)…
                      (Apple_Free : 3): verified   CRC32 $00000000
  Checksumming EFI System Partition (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B : 4)…
  ....
  EFI System Partition (C12A7328-F81F-: verified   CRC32 $B54B659C
  Checksumming disk image (Apple_HFS : 5)…
  .................................................................................................................................
            disk image (Apple_HFS : 5): verified   CRC32 $F1A0F123
  Checksumming  (Apple_Free : 6)…
  ...................................................................................................................................
                      (Apple_Free : 6): verified   CRC32 $00000000
  Checksumming GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 7)…
  ...................................................................................................................................
  GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table: verified   CRC32 $8F9F9AF5
  Checksumming GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 8)…
  ....................................................................................................................................
    GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 8): verified   CRC32 $5826D5C7
  ....................................................................................................................................
  verified   CRC32 $BE5D6293
  hdiutil: verify: checksum of "/Volumes/Install OS X El Capitan/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" is VALID
  ```

  **Some of the CRC32 values may be different in your output!**
- Reboot you Mac with the thumb drive attached and hold the <kbd>alt/opt</kbd> button. If the thumb drive doesn't show up on the first run just repeat the step. It took me 2 tries to successfully boot to the installer thumb drive.

Comment: you Sir are a GOD!! One side-note: I had the same error message. I am installing the complete El Capitan (not an update as the op), so I had to get the complete El Capitan Installer from Apple. To save anyone with the trouble that has my same situation, here is the link for the complete El Capitan Installer from Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886 Thanks again @klanomath!!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can mount the SSD in an external enclosure, run the Install OSX app on a working computer, and point it to the external device.  Afterwards, you should then be able to remove the drive from the enclosure and swap it in to your computer.